# Tracker.Current is not initialized when accessed from another web portal

Tags: goals

I need to trigger goals dynamically in Sitecore from an independent web portal.
The user clicks on a button and I make a rest api call to my sitecore service

var catId= 'clothing';

var url = 'https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/itemaccess/' + catId

I get the error: Tracker.Current is not initialized.

What am I doing wrong? Can I even do it this way?

My controller code is:

```
[Route("sitecore/api/ssc/itemaccess/{catId}")]
public class TriggerGoalController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string catId)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive)
            {
                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.StartTracking();
            }

            if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
            {



                var goalItem = //getGoalItem logic;

                if (goalItem != null)
                {

                    var goalTrigger = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[goalItem.ID.ToGuid()];
                    var goalEventData = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal(goalTrigger);
                    goalEventData.Data = goalItem[goalTrigger.Name];
                    goalEventData.ItemId = goalItem.ID.ToGuid();
                    goalEventData.DataKey = goalItem.Paths.Path;
                                            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
                    return goalTrigger.Name;
                }
            }
            return "Something went wrong";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tracker.Current` relies on HTTP Session Context existing.  Web API does not instantiate a Session object, thereby making Tracker completely unusable.

You can only use Tracker in the context of a Web Page / Controller-View Rendering. For a walkthrough on what the Tracker is doing and a full explanation on how to troubleshoot these types of issues, you can visit this blog post: [Analytics Tracker Common Issues and How to Resolve Them](https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/02/12/sitecore-analytics-tracker-common-issues-and-how-to-resolve-them)

Instead, what you might want to consider is using xConnect to register the goal/interaction.

Taken from Jason Wilkerson's [great blog post](https://citizensitecore.com/2017/10/17/xconnect-adding-interactions-in-sitecore-9/) on the subject:

```
using (var client = GetClient())
{
     var contactReference = new IdentifiedContactReference("twitter", "longhorntaco");
     var contact = client.Get(contactReference, new ExpandOptions() { FacetKeys = { "Personal" } });


 if (contact != null)
 {
     // Item ID of the "Enter Store" Offline Channel at
     // /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Channel/Offline/Store/Enter store
     var enterStoreChannelId = Guid.Parse("{3FC61BB8-0D9F-48C7-9BBD-D739DCBBE032}");
     var userAgent = "xConnectIntro Console App";

     var interaction = new Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Contact, enterStoreChannelId, userAgent);

     var productPurchaseOutcomeId = Guid.Parse("{9016E456-95CB-42E9-AD58-997D6D77AE83}");
     var outcome = new Outcome(productPurchaseOutcomeId, DateTime.UtcNow, "USD", 42.95m);

     interaction.Events.Add(outcome);

     client.AddInteraction(interaction);
     client.Submit();
 }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you explain to me what the two parameters into the Identified Contact Reference are? ANd the facetkeys?



     var contactReference = new IdentifiedContactReference("twitter", "longhorntaco");

Comment: Contacts need to be identified. So, the Contact Identifier needs a source and an identifier in order to get the contact. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/contact-identifiers.html  Facet Keys, are the facets (which contain information about a contact) that you want to expand and populate into your object. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/facets.html